# How to concatenate the string value to the integer value in Jquery?

Tags: jquery, for-loop, concatenation

How to concatenate the integer value with the string in jquery.
i am using google maps and working with the map markers.

```
     for (var x = 0; x < addresses.length; x++) {
 infowindow1.open(map,x);
}
```

here how i can concatenate the variable 'x' with the infowindow to make it infowindow1,infowindow2 and so on

any hint ?

Comment: is the variables present in the global scope? if so then `window['infowindow' + x]`... because global variables are properties of the window object

Comment: if not you can't use it as a variable... instead you can create those values as properties of another object and use that object along with the bracket notation as shown above to access it

Comment: how is those variables created

Comment: i have declare the variable in the for loop

Answer (score 0):

Like this maybe:

```
for (var x = 0; x < addresses.length; x++) {
   window["infowindow"+x].open(map,x);
}
```

It works only if `infowindow` + anynumber is in a global scope.

Comment: how to define the variable scope in jquery ?

Comment: Its a big topic. Search for javascript variable scope in google. Sorry ;)